# Fastest way to sequential change of UIButton hidden or hide

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I want to have a function that by pressing the 1st button, then the 2nd button will be appear. When the 2nd button appear, after pressing it, then the 3rd button will appear and so on until the 10th button.

Making IBAction for each button can do the job. But it will be very time consuming. And I have multiple of these sequence needed to be done.

Is there any other way is faster and simpler to get this job done?

Thanks

Comment: Assign 10 button's tag from 0 to 9, then set all 10 UIButtons' action with the same action selector '- (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender', then check sender.tag to show the UIButton whose tag is `sender.tag%9 + 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose, you have to use the `tag` property of `UIButton`. while creating the `UIButton` set the tag value. For example for button1 it should be `1`, for button2 it should be `2`, and so on...

After that set the same `IBAction` for all UIButtons. And inside that `IBAction` get the button based on `tag` value and unhide next `UIButton`.

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
     UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:(sender.tag + 1)];
     button.hidden = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be use loop for these process . . .

(if second button not appear only on first button click)

Comment: This should be a comment, and not an answer. If you want it to be an answer, consider writing a complete answer.